# how do I update the array in the laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

how to update using an array in Laravel?
how do I update the array in the Laravel controller?
An error occurred during the data update
I have displayed the view and controller

need his help

> controller

```
public function update_pesanan(Request $request,$id)
{
    DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
    ->where('a.id_paket', $id)
    ->update([
    'harga_satuan' => $request->harga_satuan
     ]);
    return redirect ()->back()->with('success','Berhasil Menambahkan Penawaran!');
}
```

> view

```
<form action="/update_pesanan/{{ $p->id_paket }}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 20px;">Kode BMN</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">Nama Barang</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Kuantitas</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Satuan Ukuran</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 20px;">Kode Unit</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Harga Satuan</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  @foreach($pesanan as $key => $p)
  <tbody>
    <tr id="addRow" >
      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_bmn}}
      </td>

      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->jenis_barang}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kuantitas}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->satuan_ukuran}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_ruang}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control " name="harga_satuan[$key] " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
</table>
  <div class="col-md-1 pull-right"><br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helpful...

**Controller:**

```
public function update_pesanan(Request $request)
{
    $update_id= $request->input('update_id');
    $harga_satuan = $request->input('harga_satuan');

    for($i=0; $i < count($harga_satuan); $i++) {
      DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
      ->where('a.id_paket', $update_id[$i])
      ->update([
          'harga_satuan' => $harga_satuan[$i]
      ]);
    }
    return redirect ()->back()->with('success','Berhasil Menambahkan Penawaran!');
}
```

**View:**

```
    <input class="form-control " name="harga_satuan[$key] " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />

    <input class="form-control " name="update_id[$key] " type="hidden" value="{{ $p->id_paket }}" />
```

Comment: what if an array?

Answer (score 0):

try using **json_encode()** and when you reuse saved data you have to decode using **json_decode()**

```
DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
    ->where('a.id_paket', $id)
    ->update([
    'harga_satuan' => json_encode($request->harga_satuan)
     ]);
```

Comment: it will display more than one in the field

Comment: there are 3 rows for one `$id` so you want save as 3 rows or in one   row ?

Comment: in your form action `{{ $p->id_paket }}` how you get `$p` here ?